# PlayScala form mapping

Tags: forms, scala, playframework

I'm trying to create a form field mapping formatter based on the data value and map respectively to its class.

```
sealed trait Animal
case class MammalFormData(name: String, hairy: Boolean) extends Animal
case class BirdFormData(name: String, featherType: String) extends Animal

val studentForm = Form(mapping(
   "name" -> nonEmptyText,
   "height" -> of[Double],
   "pet" -> of[Animal](AnimalFormatter)
)(Student.apply)(Student.unapply))
```

And then i have to create a formatter for the `Animal` data object in the following

```
object AnimalFormatter extends Formatter[Animal] {
  def bind(key: String, data: Map[String, String]) // How do i complete here

  def unbind....
}
```

How can i complete the `bind` section of the `AnimalFormatter` object with the following json form data structure?

```
{
 "name": "Jared Smith",
 "height": 5.2,
 "petType": "mammal",
 "pet": {
   "name": "Aaron Meow",
   "hairy": true
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, I worked around it using `Json` validation to validate the data. But I support the idea of clever code so I reverted to forms implementing the `Formatter` in a couple of tests.

For the data

```
{
 "name": "Jared Smith",
 "height": 5.2,
 "petType": "mammal",
 "pet": {
   "name": "Aaron Meow",
   "hairy": true
  }
}
```

The discriminator to determine the type of animal is `petType`.
The necessity here is to extract the sub-data of `pet` to a new `petDataMap`.

```
object AnimalFormatter extends Formatter[Animal] {
  def bind(key: String, data: Map[String, String]): Either[Seq[FormError], Animal] = {
    // Most necessary
    val petDataMap = data
      .filter(_._1.startsWith(s"$key."))
      .map(kv => (kv._1.split('.').tail.mkString("."), kv._2))

    data.get("petType") match {
      case Some("mammal") =>
        mammalFormDataMapping.bind(petDataMap)

      case Some("bird") =>
        birdFormDataMapping.bind(petDataMap)

      case _=> Left(Seq(FormError("petType", "invalid.petType")))
    }
 }

  def unbind....
}
```